# How do I detect the black region in a threshold image

Tags: python, image-processing

How can I detect a black region in a threshold image? and

how do I draw the contour of this black area?

[image: enter image description here[1]]

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code so that we can get a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: show your code as text

Comment: how do I draw the contour of the black area in the frame named 'kirpil'

Comment: Your question is too vague for us to give you an answer. Do you have a specific block of code that you need help with? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post the actual code and the actual image you’re talking about. A screen shot is mostly useless to anyone that might try to help you, as that person would need to type in all your code from there, rather than just copy-paste, and try to extract the image data to try the code on is hard too. Screen shots are also not accessible to some people, and are not indexable, meaning that people searching for a similar problem will less likely find your question.

Answer (score 3):

First of, it is best if you provide your code as text in a code markdown (try to avoid screenshots of code).

As for your question, this OpenCV [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) explains this in a great length. Noteworthy, you first need to find contours with `cv2.findContours` function, and then draw them with `cv2.drawContours` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

where `thresh` is your thresholded image.